# At what points the application ceases to be an immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, projective-space

The application $f: S^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f (x, y, z) = (yz, xz, xy)$ induces an application of class $C^1$ of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But it is not an immersion in $6$ points, I am not able to find these points in which the differential is not injecting and its images are points of the coordinated axes?

Could someone give me a hint how to find them, please?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^2$ is the projective space.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence in the quesstion. If $(x,y,z)$ represents a point in $\mathbb RP^2$, then $(2x,2y,2z)$ represents the same point, because homogeneous coordinates in projective space are defined only up to a constant factor. But your formula for $f$ implies that $f(2x,2y,2z)=4f(x,y,z)$, and here the factor $4$ matters because the values of $f$ are asserted to be in $\mathbb R^3$, not in $\mathbb RP^2$. So your $f$ is not a function.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: It's fine. Think of $\Bbb RP^2 = S^2/(x\sim -x)$ and note that $f(-x,-y,-z)=f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right; I overlooked the restriction that the homogeneous coordinates were required to be on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Your function $f$ has a natural extension $\widetilde{f}\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, and we have no choice but to compute $${\rm d}\widetilde{f}_{(x,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & z & y \\ z & 0 & x \\ y & x & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$However, the domain of the differential ${\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)}$ is the tangent space $T_{(x,y,z)}\Bbb S^2 = (x,y,z)^\perp$. Observe that $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & z & y \\ z & 0 & x \\ y & x & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2yz \\ 2xz \\ 2xy \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$since $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$. So ${\rm rank}({\rm d}\widetilde{f}_{(x,y,z)}) = {\rm rank}({\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)}) + 1$, and ${\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)}$ will have full rank if an only if ${\rm d}\widetilde{f}_{(x,y,z)}$ has full rank, and the question becomes: what are the points $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb S^2$ for which this matrix does not have full-rank?

- Can it have rank $0$? No, because $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ implies $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$, and so ${\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)} \neq 0$.
- Can it have rank $1$? This would mean that every order two subdeterminant vanishes. This also implies that $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$, by looking at the submatrices $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ \ast & 0\end{bmatrix}$, with $\ast \in \{x,y,z\}$.
- Can it have rank $2$? This means that $\det {\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)} = 0$. But this equals $$\det {\rm d}f_{(x,y,z)} = 0 + xyz + xyz - 0 - 0 - 0 = 2xyz.$$If $x = 0$, then $y^2+z^2 = 1$ gives us $4$ critical points. If $y = 0$, $x^2+z^2=1$ gives us $4$ more critical points. And from $z=0$, $x^2+y^2=1$ gives another $4$ critical points.

These $12$ critical points in $\Bbb S^2$ pass to the quotient as $6$ critical points in $\Bbb R P^2$.

Comment: Be careful here. You're considering the derivative of a mapping $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$. You have to translate this into information about the derivative of a mapping of $S^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$? Just restricting $(x,y,z)$ to the sphere does not suffice.

Comment: No? Shoot. Is there a (nice) way to do this without using coordinates then?

Comment: Alright, fixed? :)

Comment: Well, $\bar{f}(\{-p,p\}) = f(p)$ right? So $\{-p,p\}$ is a critical point of $\bar{f}$ if $p$ is a critical point of $f$. But critical points of $f$ come in antipodal pairs, that's why it cuts down from $12$ to $6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use spherical coordinates, which are safe away from the poles ($\sin \phi= 0$)

$$(x,y,z)=(\cos\theta\sin\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi)$$

Then writing $f$ as a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$, we have 
$$f(\theta,\phi) = \newcommand\bmat{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand\emat{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat 
\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi\\
\sin\theta\cos\theta\sin^2\phi
\emat
=
\frac{1}{2}
\bmat
\sin\theta\sin 2\phi\\
\cos\theta\sin 2\phi\\
\sin 2\theta\sin^2\phi\\
\emat
$$

$$
df = 
\frac{1}{2}
\bmat
\cos\theta\sin2\phi &
2\sin\theta\cos2\phi\\
-\sin\theta \sin2\phi &
2\cos\theta\cos2\phi\\
2\cos2\theta\sin^2\phi &
\sin2\theta\sin 2\phi
\emat.
$$

The first $2\times 2$ minor is
$$2\cos^2\theta\sin2\phi\cos 2 \phi +2\sin^2\theta\sin2\phi\cos 2\phi=2\sin 2\phi\cos 2\phi.$$

In order for $df$ to have low rank, this must be $0$, so either $\sin 2\phi=0$ or $\cos 2\phi =0$. Note that $\phi \in (0,\pi)$. Thus either $\phi = \pi/2$ or $\phi = \pi/4,3\pi/4$.

These correspond to three possibilities for $df$.

When $\phi = \pi/4$, 
$$
df = 
\frac{1}{2}
\bmat
\cos\theta &
0\\
-\sin\theta  &
0\\
\cos2\theta &
\sin2\theta
\emat,
$$
this has low rank when $\sin 2\theta = 0$, corresponding to $\theta = n\pi/2$, $n\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Similarly, when $\phi = 3\pi/4$, we end up with
$$
df = 
\frac{1}{2}
\bmat
-\cos\theta &
0\\
\sin\theta  &
0\\
\cos2\theta &
-\sin2\theta
\emat,
$$
which also has low rank at $\theta = n\pi/2$.

Finally, when $\phi = \pi/2$, we have 
$$
df = 
\frac{1}{2}
\bmat
0 &
-2\sin\theta\\
0 &
-2\cos\theta\\
2\cos2\theta &
0
\emat.
$$

This has low rank if and only if $\cos 2\theta = 0$, corresponding to $\theta = \pi/4 + n\pi/2$.

Let $a = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for notational convenience.

Translating back into rectangular coordinates, $f$ has low rank at the following twelve points:
$(\pm a, 0, \pm a)$, $(0,\pm a, \pm a)$, and $(\pm a, \pm a, 0)$.

These descend to $6$ points where $f$ has low rank on the projective plane.

Since none of these are the points $(\pm 1,0,0)$ or $(0,\pm 1,0)$ we don't need to worry about the fact that we excluded the poles at the beginning, since by symmetry they can't be points where $f$ has low rank.